# Unique Key Constraint Validation MVC 4 (Fluent API)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fluent

My project is divided in Controller, Models, Services, Parameters and Views. 
I don't use EF. 
I try use this code for validate Unique Key Constraint, but for the EF.

```
public static ValidationResult IsUserNameUnique(object username, ValidationContext context)
{
            ADMINEntities x = new ADMINEntities();
            var users = from u in x.Users
                        select u;
            foreach (var item in users)
            {
                if (item.Username == username.ToString())
                {
                    return new ValidationResult("Username is already choosen, please choose another one.");

                }
            }
            return ValidationResult.Success;
}
```

how to i change the code to suit fluent?
No have edmx.
No have Context.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more what exactly do you want to achieve? Currently it is not very clear what and where the problem is.

Comment: exacly.. about it. I wish he could go through the list of users and checks if the user exists, if any  not let create the order. That is validation that would

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, that you want to remove the `foreach` loop and have a more succinct code. An equivalent, but shorter query could be written using the [FirstOrDefault extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549039%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var x = new ADMINEntities();
var usersExists = x.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == username.ToString());
return usersExists != null
            ? new ValidationResult("Username is already choosen, please choose another one.")
            : ValidationResult.Success;
```